# How to reverse the order of y labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I reverse the order of my y labels? Category A should be at the top and N an the bottom.

My file `datatable.txt`:

```
one two three
A   2   0.3
B   3   0.4
C   4   0.5
D   5   0.6
E   4   0.7
F   3   0.6
G   2   0.5
H   3   0.4
I   4   0.3
J   5   0.4
K   4   0.5
L   3   0.6
M   2   0.7
N   3   0.6
```

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=6,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one}
]
\addplot plot [error bars/.cd, x dir = both, x explicit] table [x=two, y expr=\coordindex, x error = three] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xbars and standard deviations}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two easy ways to achieve that would be to

- either add `y dir=reverse` to the `axis` environment options,
- or to write `y expr=-\coordindex` (notice the added minus sign).

---

```
\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two three
A   2   0.3
B   3   0.4
C   4   0.5
D   5   0.6
E   4   0.7
F   3   0.6
G   2   0.5
H   3   0.4
I   4   0.3
J   5   0.4
K   4   0.5
L   3   0.6
M   2   0.7
N   3   0.6
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        my axis style/.style={
            xbar,
            xmin=1,
            xmax=6,
            ytick=data,
            yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one},
            error bars/x dir=both,
            error bars/x explicit,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        y dir=reverse,              % <-- added style
    ]
        \addplot table [
            x=two,
            y expr=\coordindex,
            x error=three,
        ] {datatable.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
    ]
        \addplot table [
            x=two,
            y expr=-\coordindex,    % <-- added minus sign
            x error=three,
        ] {datatable.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

The y-axis can be reordered by declaring `symbolic y cords` in the desired order for plotting. Then you need to delete the `yticklabels from table` and replace `y expr=\coordindex` with `y=one`, corresponding to the labels that identify each xbar. To make the MWE self-contained, the data are incorporated in the file and read using `\pgfplotstable`.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
    one two three
    A   2   0.3
    B   3   0.4
    C   4   0.5
    D   5   0.6
    E   4   0.7
    F   3   0.6
    G   2   0.5
    H   3   0.4
    I   4   0.3
    J   5   0.4
    K   4   0.5
    L   3   0.6
    M   2   0.7
    N   3   0.6
}\data

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=10cm, height=10cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=6,
    symbolic y coords={N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A},
    ytick=data,
]
\addplot [
   error bars/.cd,
   x dir = both,
   x explicit,
   ] table [
   x=two,
   y=one, 
   x error = three
   ] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xbars and standard deviations}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```