# Delete ytick dashes in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can I delete the little dashes on both vertical axis? There shouldn't be any dashes between the label and the xbar.

My file `datatable.txt`:

```
one two three
A   2   0.3
B   3   0.4
C   4   0.5
D   5   0.6
E   4   0.7
F   3   0.6
G   2   0.5
H   3   0.4
I   4   0.3
J   5   0.4
K   4   0.5
L   3   0.6
M   2   0.7
N   3   0.6
```

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=6,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one}
]
\addplot plot [error bars/.cd, x dir = both, x explicit] table [x=two, y expr=\coordindex, x error = three] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xbars and standard deviations}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ytick style={draw=none}` as Ross suggested in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388117) you could/should use `major tick length=0pt` for the `yticks` so also the distance of the `yticklabels` are adjusted properly.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two three
A   2   0.3
B   3   0.4
C   4   0.5
D   5   0.6
E   4   0.7
F   3   0.6
G   2   0.5
H   3   0.4
I   4   0.3
J   5   0.4
K   4   0.5
L   3   0.6
M   2   0.7
N   3   0.6
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        xmin=1,
        xmax=6,
        ytick=data,
        yticklabels from table={datatable.txt}{one},
        error bars/x dir=both,
        error bars/x explicit,
        y dir=reverse,
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % (just added to illustrate the problem when using Ross' solution
%        %  <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388117> or the following commented one)
%        major tick length=50pt,
%        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % simply set the tick length for the y ticks to zero,
%        % but then the distance to of the ticklabels isn't adjusted
%        % (maybe this is a bug?)
%        ytick style={
%            /pgfplots/major tick length=0pt,
%        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % to circumvent that problem, first set (all) tick length to zero
        % and and then restore the default length for the xticks
        % doing that the yticklabels have the "right" distance to the y-axis
        % (compare with the distance of the xticklabels to the x-axis)
        major tick length=0pt,
        xtick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=1.5mm,
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot table [
            x=two,
            y expr=\coordindex,
            x error=three,
        ] {datatable.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 4):

Add `ytick style={draw=none}` to the axis options. I used the MWE from this answer [How to reverse the order of ylabels in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388099/)

This is the result:
[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
    one two three
    A   2   0.3
    B   3   0.4
    C   4   0.5
    D   5   0.6
    E   4   0.7
    F   3   0.6
    G   2   0.5
    H   3   0.4
    I   4   0.3
    J   5   0.4
    K   4   0.5
    L   3   0.6
    M   2   0.7
    N   3   0.6
}\data

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=10cm, height=10cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=6,
    symbolic y coords={N,M,L,K,J,I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A},
    ytick=data,
    ytick style={draw=none}
]
\addplot [
   error bars/.cd,
   x dir = both,
   x explicit,
   ] table [
   x=two,
   y=one, 
   x error = three
   ] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{xbars and standard deviations}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but has one downside which you can illustrate when you e.g. add `major tick length=50pt` to the `axis` options ... For more details please have a look at [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388145).

Comment: @Stefan. I agree. Your solution is preferable.