# Removing ticks from top, bottom and right-hand side of column chart and rename x-axis labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, columns, ticks

I am trying to make a nice looking histogram of my data, and have managed to produce the following so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=8000,
    minor y tick num = 2,
    axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
    area style,
    ]
\addplot+ [ybar interval,mark=no, fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135},draw=gray!5] plot coordinates { (0, 32) (5, 1228) (10, 6658) (15, 5060) (20, 1786) (25, 684) (30, 404) (35, 228) (40, 165) (45, 119) (50, 72)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But, I do have some small inquiries remaining, which I have not been able to solve. These are:

1) I would like to remove the small ticks from the top and bottom x-axis, along with the right y-axis. How would I go about this?

2) How would I change the label names on the x-axis? I would like it to say 0.0x, 10.0x, 20.0x etc. How would I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So this is what you are searching for ...?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=0,
        ymax=8000,
        minor y tick num = 2,
        axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
        area style,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % to 1)
        % only show left ticks (instead of left and right)
        ytick pos=lower,
        % remove xticks
        xtick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=0pt,
        },
        % to 2)
        xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$x},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot+ [
            ybar interval,
            fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135},
            draw=gray!5,
        ] coordinates {
            (0, 32)
            (5, 1228)
            (10, 6658)
            (15, 5060)
            (20, 1786)
            (25, 684)
            (30, 404)
            (35, 228)
            (40, 165)
            (45, 119)
            (50, 72)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Or you could use `xtick style={draw=none},`

Comment: @hpekristiansen, you are right, but this only works fine/as expected, as long as the ticks are _inside_ (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388145/95441).